# generating DataFrames in for loop in Scala Spark cause out of memory

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I'm generating small dataFrames in for loop. At each round of for loop, I pass the generated dataFrame to a function which returns double. This simple process (which I thought could be easily taken care of by garbage collector) blow up my memory. When I look at Spark UI at each round of for loop it adds a new  "SQL{1-500}" (my loop runs 500 times). My question is how to drop this sql object before generating a new one?

my code is something like this:

```
Seq.fill(500){
  val data = (1 to 1000).map(_=>Random.nextInt(1000))
  val dataframe = createDataFrame(data)
  myFunction(dataframe)
  dataframe.unpersist()
}

def myFunction(df: DataFrame)={
  df.count()
}
```

I tried to solve this problem by dataframe.unpersist() and sqlContext.clearCache() but neither of them worked.

Comment: You want to create 500 DataFrames?

Comment: yes but I don't want to keep all of them in the memory. I want to process the first one, remove it from the memory generate the second one and process it ....

Comment: And what's your cluster configuration?

Comment: I used this: new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local")
      .setAppName("test"). when I try to increase the partitions by  .setMaster("local[10]") I run in to out of heap memory abit faster. My heap memory size is 4G

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two places where I suspect something fishy is happening:

- in the definition of `myFunction` : you really need to put the `=` before the body of the definition. I had typos like that compile, but produce really weird errors (note I changed your myFunction for debugging purposes)
- it is better to fill your Seq with something you know and then apply foreach or some such

(You also need to replace `random.nexInt` with `Random.nextInt`, and also, you can only create a DataFrame from a Seq of a type that is a subtype of Product, such as tuple, and need to use sqlContext to use createDataFrame)

This code works with no memory issues:

```
Seq.fill(500)(0).foreach{ i => 
  val data = {1 to 1000}.map(_.toDouble).toList.zipWithIndex
  val dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data)
  myFunction(dataframe)
}

def myFunction(df: DataFrame) = {
  println(df.count())
}
```

**Edit**: parallelizing the computation (across 10 cores) and returning the RDD of counts:

```
sc.parallelize(Seq.fill(500)(0), 10).map{ i => 
  val data = {1 to 1000}.map(_.toDouble).toList.zipWithIndex
  val dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data)
  myFunction(dataframe)
}

def myFunction(df: DataFrame) = {
  df.count()
}
```

**Edit 2**: the difference between declaring function `myFunction` with `=` and without `=` is that the first is (a usual) function definition, while the other is procedure definition and is only used for methods that return Unit. See [explanation](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1849236&seqNum=10). Here is this point illustrated in Spark-shell:

```
scala> def myf(df:DataFrame) = df.count()
myf: (df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)Long

scala> def myf2(df:DataFrame) { df.count() }
myf2: (df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)Unit
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I corrected the typos in my example and you are right the code you posted doesn't show any memory issue (though I want my Seq to be filled with count of rows of dataFrames). I have to dig more.

Comment: If you want to fill with counts, you need only use map instead of foreach. Foreach has no side effects and is only used for printing, map actually maps each element to a new one.   Also, if you want to parallelize your computation, you want to use an RDD, not a Seq. Seq exists in the driver only, an RDD will actually split your computation across different cores/nodes

Comment: I know but the Seq has only 500 to 2000 elements and can be very well handled in the memory.

Comment: I just wanted to add this as a comment for futue reference. This point is not eflected in my question. What I was actually doing was to load a trained Naive Bayes model(using mlib library) repeatedly in  for loop. In normal situation this shouldnt cause a memory problem but it seems here due to a spark bug, every time I load the model it get stucks in the memory and this memory leak results in out of memory problem eventually.